# Why is Brew installed postgres looking here?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, postgresql-9.2, rails-postgresql

Why is brew installed postgres looking for `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` when I specified `/var/pgsql_socket` (`unix_socket_directory = '/var/pgsql_socket'`) in my `postgresql.conf`?

Install was successful. I can start and stop Pg successfully.

My `PATH` and `PGHOST` env vars seem to be set up correctly, but when I try `psql`, I cannot connect?

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PGHOST="/var/pgsql_socket"
```

Any ideas?  I've read 1000 posts, and nothing seems to fit my situation and provide a fix?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `unix_socket_directory` in `postgresql.conf` only affects where the server puts the socket directory. `postgresql.conf` isn't readable by clients, and clients can't ask the server about settings until they can connect, so a chicken-and-egg problem prevents the client asking the server how to connect.

You need to tell `psql` where the socket directory is. It appears you've already done this with `pghost`, so my guess is that you haven't *exported* the environment variables:

```
export PGHOST="/var/pgsql_socket"
```

or

```
psql -h /var/pgsql_socket
```

Comment: you may be correct; I am setting PGHOST in my .bash_profile, PGHOST="blah blah", but not exporting it like you indicate although if I do $ echo $PGHOST from the command line, "/var/pgsql_socket" is displayed properly.  I am not (yet, obviously) a unix guru :(

Comment: that was it! I searched like 100 posts no one delved in to that level of n00b, thanks :)